# How to tag a Facebook page using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to post to Facebook in iOS 6 and have that working fine. However, when I try to tag a Facebook page by including @pagename in the message, the raw text '@pagename' is posted and is not linked to the page. I am able to do this directly on Facebooks website so I know that the page name is correct. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I have determined that this is not possible with the current UIActivityViewController API. Even if it did work, you need to 'like' a page before you can tag it, so this will not work for my situation.